# Deleting an extension which has no means to be uninstalled

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vsix

I have an [extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d941448c-791f-4771-9839-04f7f7266e40) installed in VS 2010  but there is no option to uninstall it from extension manager or add/remove programs (if it was in an msi, can't remember). Add-in manager gives me the option to *disable* the extension, but it still comes up when I restart VS2010 (always running in Administrator mode btw). I also looked in my Local folder under VisualStudio/Extensions.

I've checked the registry for entries for this extension, but can't find anything, either. What can I do (except reinstall VS2010)?

Thanks

Comment: The only time I've seen this is when the extension is installed by an admin and the account trying to uninstall is a normal user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has `uninstall` option in installer. Download it again (using your link) and click `uninstall`.

Comment: Tried to do that, but the installer throws an UnauthorizedAccessException (I made the path not read only too).

Comment: Then another guess is to use `ProcessMonitor` to understand which resources installer tries to access.

Comment: Fixed by installing the newer version on top.